# Golang JSON encoding for parsing with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, go

I have a struct like this:

```
type User struct {
  Login         string    `json:",string"`
  PasswordNonce Nonce     `json:",string"`
  PasswordHash  HashValue `json:",string"`
  CreatedOn     time.Time `json:",string"`
  Email         string    `json:",string"`
  PhoneNumber   string    `json:",string"`
  UserId        Id        `json:",string"`
}
```

The code that generates the JSON and sends it is the following:

```
func AddUserHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var userRecord model.User
    encoder := json.NewEncoder(w)
    err = encoder.Encode(userRecord)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

When I encode it with the Golang built in JSON encoder, the field names appear without quotes, which prevents the JSON.parse function in node.js from reading the content.
Does anyone know a solution to that?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you are using json.Marshal right?

Comment: I was using `encoder := json.NewEncoder(w)` and then `encoder.Encode(data)` where w is an `http.ResponseWriter`

Comment: Can you please post that bit of code? It may be relevant.

Comment: Sure, adding it to the question...

Comment: Just to clarify, Nonce and HashValue are both the type `[32]byte`

Comment: and Id is the same [32]byte as well?

Comment: Yes, Id is also [32]byte.

Answer (score 2):

It was my mistake. The problem was in the Javascript code.
I am using the node.js request package, and it seems to parse JSON responses by default. In the following code, response.body is already a map containing the parsed contents of the JSON string:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    uri: 'http://localhost:3000/AddUser',
    method: 'POST',
    json: {}
};

request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(error)
    console.log(response.body)
    console.log(response.body["UserId"])
    data = response.body
    // data = JSON.parse(response.body) gives an error...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type Nonce [32]byte
type HashValue [32]byte
type Id [32]byte

func MakeNonce() Nonce {
    return makeByte32()
}

func MakeHashValue() HashValue {
    return makeByte32()
}

func MakeId() Id {
    return makeByte32()
}

func makeByte32() [32]byte {
    bytes := [32]byte{}
    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    for i, _ := range bytes {
        bytes[i] = byte(48 + (rand.Float64() * 10))
    }
    return bytes
}

type User struct {
    Login         string
    PasswordNonce Nonce
    PasswordHash  HashValue
    CreatedOn     time.Time
    Email         string
    PhoneNumber   string
    UserId        Id
}

type myHandler struct {
    userRecord User
}

func (mh myHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    encoder := json.NewEncoder(w)
    err := encoder.Encode(mh.userRecord)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    user := User{
        "test",
        MakeNonce(),
        MakeHashValue(),
        time.Now(),
        "test@test.com",
        "5195555555",
        MakeId(),
    }

    h := myHandler{user}
    http.ListenAndServe("localhost:4000", h)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `json.Marshal`

```
jsonData, err := json.Marshal(data)
```